# jQuery calculation with HTML

Tags: jquery

I need to calculate input values using jQuery. If the input Gvalue is 100 and selected percentage is 10% then in the final value it should display a total value of 110 which should be like this 100*10% + 100 = 110.

```
value
<input type="text" name="gvalue"  class="input" required/>

Percentage
<select name="percent" id="percent" class="input" onchange="setStates();">
  <option value="Country" selected>Select Percentage</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>

Final Value
<input type="text" name="flvalue"  class="input" id="#total" required/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an event handler and calculate the total based on input values.

```js
// bind event handler to both input and select tag
$('#percent,#input').on('change input', function() {
  // parse input field value, if NaN treat as 0
  var val = Number($('#input').val()) || 0,
    // parse select field value, if NaN treat as 0
    per = Number($('#percent').val()) || 0;
  // calculate and update the total
  $('#total').val(val + val * per / 100)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
value
<input type="text" name="gvalue" id="input" class="input" required/>Percentage
<select name="percent" id="percent" class="input">
  <option value="Country" selected>Select Percentage</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>

Final Value
<input type="text" name="flvalue" class="input" id="total" required/>
```

Comment: I need onchange event it has another query <select name="percent" id="percent" class="input" onchange="setStates();">

Comment: @udhay do the same within that function

Comment: Thanks buddy that's not an error there was another mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name="percent"]', function(){
  var total = parseInt($('input[name="gvalue"]').val()) /   (parseInt($('select[name="percent"]').val()) / 100 ) + 100)
$('input[name="flvalue"]').val(total);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML:

```
value
<input type="text" name="gvalue" id="gvalue" class="input" required/>

Percentage
<select name="percent" id="percent" class="input" onchange="setStates();">
  <option value="Country" selected>Select Percentage</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
</select>

Final Value
<input type="text" name="flvalue"  class="input" id="total" required/>
```

Your JavaScript code:

```
<script>
    function setStates(){
        var gvalue = $('#gvalue').val();
        if(gvalue){
            var gvalue = parseInt(gvalue);
            var percent = parseInt($('#percent').val());
            var final = (gvalue*percent/100)+100;
            $('#total').val(final);
        } else {
            $('#gvalue').css('border-bottom-color','red');
        }
    }
</script>
```